# Is it possible to delay an element loading on the first page that a user visits?

Tags: javascript, jquery, delay, settimeout

A client of mine wants a live chat system implemented into their site. I can implement it just fine - and it's called in through a script tag.

They also want it to have a slight delay before it loads in. I was thinking of using setTimeout to delay the load, but it turns out that they only want that to occur on the very first visit to the site.

Is there a way to use setTimeout once, and then skip the timeout on subsequent loads for that session?

Comment: You could do this by setting a cookie. Or using localStorage (or sessionStorage)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use a cookie:**
In your script create a cookie called visited and set it equal to 'yes':

```
document.cookie="visited=yes";
```

Then check to see if a cookie with the name 'visited' exists:

```
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');     //creates an array of all cookies for the page
    for (var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {        //loops through each variable
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0)            //if there is a match, i.e. this cookie is called 'visited'
            return c.substring(name.length,c.length); //return, with the value of 'visited'
    }
    return "";
}

if (getCookie("visited") == "yes") {
    //user has previously visited site; don't delay
}
```

---

If you're looking for more lightweight solution, try this:

```
function cookieExists(cname) {
    var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            if (cookies[i].split('=')[0] == cname) return true;
            else break;
    }
    return false;
}

if(cookieExists("visited")) {
    //user has visited site before
}
```

It checks if a cookie called 'visited' exists

---

*If you want it super-condensed and don't care abount readability or maintainability, try this:*

```
function cookieExists(n){var c = document.cookie.split(';');for (var i=0;i<c.length;i++){if (c[i].split('=')[0]==n) return true; else break;}return false;}
```

Comment: Do you have any ideas as to how lightweight this solution would be? It seems fairly lightweight, but this site is a bit of a mongrel and takes its time as it is, so anything even a little heavy is really not preferable.

Comment: Well we can cut down the code a lot if there is only ever going to be one document cookie?

Comment: There is currently more than one already, and it realistically needs to stay that way.

Comment: I have updated my answer with a more lightweight alternative @HarryRay

Answer (score 0):

This is how you could do it via localStorage

```
localStorage.setItem('visited', true);

if(localStorage.getItem('visited')){
    // your delayed function here 
}
```

The only thing is support for localStorage won't cover older browsers. See: http://caniuse.com/#feat=namevalue-storage

In addition no one seems to know how long localStorage is set for. If you need the function for every unique visit to the site you could use sessionStorage (so if the same client opens the site on another visit the delay function should fire for them again).

I've made a very crude jsfiddle here (using jquery):
http://jsfiddle.net/lharby/mhf9ysqu/

Comment: That's really interesting, I'll have to look into localStorage more at another time. Thanks!